# Show for closed terms $t$ and formulas $\phi$. Given a structure $M$: $M\vDash t = \overline{t}\,^M$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Show for closed terms $t$ and formulas $\phi$. Given a structure $M$:
$$
\begin{align}
M&\vDash t = \overline{t}\,^M\\
M&\vDash \phi(t) \leftrightarrow \phi(\overline{t}\,^M)
\end{align}
$$

For the first statement, we can say that any interpretation of a closed term is the same term, so the valuation of this atomic formula gives always $1$. The other part is not than clear, because we see a formula, not necessary a sentence, so, the valuation ($1- |(\phi(t))^M -\phi(\overline{t}\,^M)|$) must be $1$. I' not sure what is the next step. How do you prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment*

> we can say that any interpretation of a closed term is the same term;

not exactly.

If $t$ is a (closed) *term* of the language, then $t^{\mathcal M}$ is its interpretation in the *structure* $\mathcal M$ while $\overline {(t^{\mathcal M})}$ is the "added" constant symbol for $t^{\mathcal M} \in |\mathcal M|$ [see page 65].

Example from the language for f-o *arithmetic* [see **Exercise 1**, page 68], i.e. for the structure :

> $\mathcal N = \langle \mathbb N ,+,·,S,0 \rangle$.

A closed *term* is e.g. :

> $S(0)+S(0)$;

if we call it $t$, then $t^{\mathcal N}$ is the *number* $2$, while the "added" constant symbol $\overline {(t^{\mathcal N})}$ is $\overline 2$.

Thus, applying clause 2 of **Definition 3.4.2**, we have to prove that:

> $[t = \overline {(t^{\mathcal M})}]_{\mathcal M}=1$

and this is so if:

> $t^{\mathcal M} = \overline {(t^{\mathcal M})}^{\mathcal M}$

which is "convoluted" but obvious: the "added" constant symbol $\overline {(t^{\mathcal M})}$ is the "name" for the object associated in the interpretation to the term $t$. Thus $\overline {(t^{\mathcal M})}^{\mathcal M}$ is the object itself.

But the object associated in the interpretation to the term $t$ is $t^{\mathcal M}$.

---

Regarding the formula $\varphi(t)$, it is *closed* and thus a *sentence*; so, we can apply **Lemma 3.4.5** (v).

Comment: This has some sense, ($\overline{t} $)? I would say no, am I right?

Comment: @jonaprieto - if I've "interpreted" van Dalen's symbolism correctly, $t$ is a *term* (i.e. part of the language: a *syntactical* objcet), while $t^M$ is its interpretation, i.e. an "object" of the *universe* of the structure $M$. The "overlining" maps an object $a$ into a "name" $\overline a$ and thus is a mapping from $|M|$ to the language $L$. If so, we have to consider $\overline {t^M}$, i.e. the "name" associated to the object $t^M$, while $\overline t$ has no sense, because $t$ is already "in" the language $L$.

Comment: Thanks, it seems more clear now.